# Combining two 16 bit registers into a 32 bit float

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

So I have a project where I am reading data from MODBUS registers.

Each register is 16 bits, and each value is 32 bits. So I have to read two registers at a time to read each value.

So what I'm doing now is reading both registers and storing them in a `regs` array and getting their bits like so:

`bits = (regs[0] << 16) + regs[1]`

then I try converting the bits to a float like this:

```
s = struct.pack('>l', bits)
final = struct.unpack('>f', s)[0]
```

And `final` should be my 32-bit float. This works pretty much all the time, however, in a few cases I get this error:

```
Read registers failed: 'l' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

And so I went back and added a print statement to see what bits looked like before I turn it into a float, and it was this: `3309382817`, which is clearly outside of that range...

So what am I doing wrong that's causing me to get this error? Is there something I am missing?

---

Update:

Just to give a bit more info, ran it again while printing the value of `regs` as well and got this:

```
[50561, 10024]  # this is the value of regs
3313575720      # this is the value of bits
```

Comment: Could you also add `print(regs)` and add the output in the question?

Comment: @CristiFati was just in the middle of doing that :) updated question

Comment: If you're using `struct` anyway, there's no need to combine the two halves yourself: `s = struct.pack('>HH', regs[0], regs[1])`.  Or you could just use `L` instead of `l` in your original code to have it treat the value as unsigned.

Comment: @jasonharper replacing my first line with what you suggested solved the problem - so what was causing the error how I was doing it? was I not accounting for a signed bit?

Comment: @Quinn: assuming that `regs[0]` and `regs[1]` are 16 bit interpreted as unsigned values (so, [0, 65535]), `(regs[0] << 16) + regs[1]` is combining them as an unsigned 32 bit value, whose valid range is [0, (1<<32) - 1]. The `l` format specifier however tells to Python you are passing in a 32 bit _signed_ value, which is restricted to [-(1<<31), (1<<31)-1], so it breaks when you pass in a value >= 1<<31, as it can be represented in an unsigned 32 bit integer, but not in a signed one.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the signed type `l` in your `struct.pack`. Use the unsigned type `L` instead.

See [Struct Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters).